# How to use React Navigation useNavigation Hook in a class component?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm a beginner in react-native. How can I use the `useNavigation` hook in a React Class Component?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[From Documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/) -
You can wrap your class component in a function component to use the hook:

```js
class MyBackButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    // Get it from props
    const { navigation } = this.props;
  }
}

// Wrap and export
export default function(props) {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return <MyBackButton {...props} navigation={navigation} />;
}
```

Comment: The same trick with useNavigate() worked for me, too. Thanks!

Comment: I couldn't understand the code snippet. Is the function 'function()' to be invoked in the render() method of the class component in order to get the navigation?

Answer (score 0):

`useNavigation` is a hooks so you should probably use it in a `functional component`. One simple example is as follow:

```js
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';

const SomeButton = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return ( 
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('HomePage')}>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}
```

Typically you use `navigation` to navigate to any other `screen`, but of course it supports whole lot of other advance features too

Comment: How to navigate from the Class Component without passing `navigation` as a prop?

Comment: You should not mix them up, when you want to use `useNavigation`, it is a hooks and you should use it in function based component, if you need navigation in your class based component, dont use `useNavigation`

Comment: Right, so what would you use as an equivalent?